# How can I whitelist a domain in Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

As you know we can add some emails in Yahoo Contacts to receive their emails in our inbox.

Usually I receive email from different people from the same domain, for example: `p1@example.com`, `p2@example.com`, etc. These email addresses aren't constant, they sometimes change.

How can I enter the mail addresses into the Yahoo contacts to receive all emails from `example.com`?

Comment: example.com is reserved for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `Options > Filters`, click on `Add Filter` and set

`"from:" "contains: @example.com" "move to folder: inbox"`.

When you click on "Save", you're done with whitelisting that domain.

Comment: Where is `Options` in Yahoo Contacts ?

Comment: Look at the upper right-hand corner while you're on the **main** Yahoo Mail screen. Click on `Options > More Options > Filters`.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting just

> @example.com

in the junk mail allowed list, nothing in front of the ampersand.  I'm not familiar with Yahoo Mail, but that is the standard approach.

Comment: Did you test it ?